Question about Nikon D200 Question regarding +/- symbol. How do I get this to stop?
I just acquired a Nikon D200 for backup and I can’t get the +/- to stop flashing in the display and through the eye piece.
Any ideas on how to remedy this?

To clarify.  Is the the +/- with or without the "Lightning bolt"?  If it is "without" then that is the exposure compensation function.  If it is "with" then that is the flash compensation function.

@PeterM Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short

@scottbb I'm clarifying what the actual issue is, not trying to answer it.

@PeterM you both asked for clarification, and then answered the question both ways of you anticipated answer. Please put it in an answer. Thanks

@scottbb Stopping the flashing is totally different from identifying what is actually flashing.

@PererM in which case, as you find out more information, you can edit your answer. You can't edit comments. Please answer in answers.

I'm with Peter ¯\(ツ)/¯ Clarify first, answer second, delete comment (if necessary) third. Optionally even edit the question.

You probably have bracketing enabled. Press the BKT button and rotate the command dial to 0F (0 frames bracketed).
